# I need to connect IBM dashDB on Bluemix with another DB2 database in corporate network to get regular feed

Tags: db2, replication, ibm-cloud, dashdb

I have created tables in dashDB on IBM Bluemix and populated those tables with data. Now I need to connect my cloud-based dashDB with the respective feeding DB2 system (V9.7) which sits behind a corporate firewall. How can I establish the connection and set up a daily feed (replication).

Comment: You asked this same question on dW Answers at this URL:
https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/264964/i-need-to-connect-ibm-bluemix-dashdb-with-another/

Answer (score 1):

Beside using another product, you can use db2 itself.

You can catalog the dashDB on your DB2 feeding system, then do export and insert there(within your v9.7 db2).

e.g.

db2 catalog tcpip node MYDASH remote DASHSERVER server 50000 
db2 catalog db BLUDB as BLUDB at node MYDASH

then export insert in another script can be controlled by cronjob...

Answer (score 0):

You could set up the IBM Secure Connector:

> http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSWHYP_2.0.0/com.ibm.apimgmt.webapi.doc/task_createconnector.html

Here is some demo video how to do this via the Bluemix "Cloud Integration" service:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mCq_7XnBBuI

This should enable you to use DataWorks to pull data from on premise.

Alternatively you could set up an on premise ETL server, such as DataStage to pull from the enterprise system and push up to dashDB in the cloud.